# Starting external process from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to start an external process from my web application. This means using *System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo* to call out and execute a console app (exe). But I then need to somehow ***make sure nothing went wrong*** during its execution **and know when the application completed** its work.

**What's the best way to both catch all possible errors and find out when it's completed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sure hope you have control of the code for the external application or you are in for a lot of headaches.  The MOST important thing to do is make sure there is no way for that application to hang and not terminate.

You can then use the WaitForExit(), ExitCode, StandardError, StandardOut to "catch all possible errors and find out when it's completed"

Answer (score 4):

It's not so hard with the Process class.  Though, the prior poster was correct - you need to be concerned about permissions.

```
private string RunProcess(string cmd)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process p; 
  p= new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  if (cmd== null || cmd=="") {
    return "no command given.";
  }
  string[] args= cmd.Split(new char[]{' '});
  if (args== null || args.Length==0 || args[0].Length==0) {
    return "no command provided.";
  }
  p.StartInfo.FileName= args[0];

  if (args.Length>1) {
    int startPoint= cmd.IndexOf(' ');
    string s= cmd.Substring(startPoint, cmd.Length-startPoint);
    p.StartInfo.Arguments= s; 
  }
  p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

  p.Start();

  // must have the readToEnd BEFORE the WaitForExit(), to avoid a deadlock condition
  string output= p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  p.WaitForExit();

  return output; 
}
```

Comment: you can replace

 cmd == null || cmd =="" 

with

 string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd)

and

 args == null

will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off catching all the output of the console app and storing it somewhere you can show it on a status page, rather than waiting for the app to finish.

As everyone else above has stated, you're going to go through pain otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Good comment. I'll make it's possible to see the output somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answer helps

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14107672/1060656

Here is a code snippet , hope this helps

http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html for cmd.exe help

```
private int CallShell(string exeCommand, string Parameters)
        {
            //http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html
            /*
            This function will actually take the shell string and envoke the appropriate process
             passing it the arguments to do the work
            */

            // Initialize the process and its StartInfo properties.
            System.Diagnostics.Process ProcessEXE = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            logger.DebugFormat("About to Start Process - {0} {1}",exeCommand, Parameters);
            try
            {

                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.FileName = exeCommand;


                // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
                //  false if the process should be created directly from the executable file
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

                //EnableRaisingEvents property indicates whether the component should be notified when the operating system has shut down a process

                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.Arguments = Parameters;

                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                ProcessEXE.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                ProcessEXE.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived);
                ProcessEXE.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived);

                logger.DebugFormat("Process Started.");
                ProcessEXE.Start();


                // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
                ProcessEXE.BeginErrorReadLine();
                ProcessEXE.BeginOutputReadLine();

                //The WaitForExit overload is used to make the current thread wait until the associated process terminates
                logger.DebugFormat("Process Waiting for exit.");
                ProcessEXE.WaitForExit();

                if (ProcessEXE.ExitCode == 0)
                {
                    logger.Debug(string.Format("Shell Process exited with exit code {0}", ProcessEXE.ExitCode));
                }
                else
                {
                // throw error here if required - check the return error code
                    logger.Warn(string.Format("Shell Process exited with exit code {0}", ProcessEXE.ExitCode));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Method:{0}", ex.TargetSite), ex);
            }

            return ProcessEXE.ExitCode;
        }


void ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
                if (e == null) return;

                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    //No processing
                }
                else
                {
                   // your logic to detect error msg out from output - if at all required
                }

                if (sb.ToString().ToUpper().IndexOf("ERROR") > 0)
                {
                    string smessage = "Error text found in  output.";

                // do your error response action here .

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                logger.ErrorFormat("Error in ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived Message:{0}", exp.Message);
                logger.ErrorFormat("Error in ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived Data Received:{0}", e.Data);

            // either throw error msg or kill the process 
            }
            finally
            {
                // Not throwing the exception
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have problems with this. ASP.NET web pages run under a tight security context and may not even be able to start an external process.

Also... ASP.NET will recycle (stop/restart all its processes) "on a whim". This means that at any moment a web page could have its execution aborted.

Have you considered using a job/task scheduler? The one that comes with SQL Server (non-express version) is very good.

Comment: NO - ASP.NET will not *at any moment* abort execution of anything.  Worker processes can recycle, but in-flight transactions are not lost, unless there is an application error.

Comment: This project isn't using SQL server and it's and external tool I'd like to start. It's not scheduled but should be triggered by a user action in the web app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch any errors from external program. Maximum you can redirect its output to your own stream and hope that it will write something when it fails/succeed. You can also check process exit code using Process.ExitCode.

You can test if process finished using Process.Exited event, or Process.HasExited property.

Also you should note that by default Asp.Net code runs under NETWORK SERVICE process(iis6 and above), so it will have limited permissions and logged in user will not be able to see it's UI.

@rbobby: you can start external process inside Asp.Net code, but it will inherit the security context of the Asp.Net code.

Comment: you can use impersonation to change the security context. Also, you can catch everything sent to stdout and stderr from System.Diagnostics.Process

Comment: To use impersonation to change security context you must know username and password. You might also configure AppPool to use different user. But not everyone will let you do it(chenage AppPool or create user).

Comment: I said that you can redirect the program output, but if program crashes, it won't help you.

Comment: The security is OK. I'm running it under a different account already set by the user of the application pool.