# Checking if process returned an error | C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

After declaring & starting a process as below:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process _p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
.....
.....
....
_p.Start();
```

There are two possibilities now: Either an output or an error.

In case an error happens, is there any property of `Process` class by which to know if error occurred?

I am redirecting the standard output, I don't want to redirect standard Error [as warned in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx). 
Also I don't want to use: `BeginOutputReadLine();`

Are there any alternatives?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the process you are starting return proper exit codes (e.g. `0` for success, `1` for error)? If so, you could check `_p.ExitCode` once the process has exited.

Comment: @Cory Many Thanks. My custom processes I was starting didnt had any exit codes. But now I implemented those & checked _p.ExitCode and its working perfect. Thanks once again.

Comment: You say you don't want to redirect std err `as warned in MSDN` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx), maybe it's my English comprehension, but I don't see anywhere in the article warning you against redirecting std err, only how to do it to prevent a deadlock

Comment: Yes, you are right Jason. Here i don't know whether my processes will run successfully or have an error & at same time I dont want to use Beginoutputreadline(), which is mentioned to avoid deadlock. What i needed was : only if error happens i wanted to read std error, else std output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a service that needs to start processes and wait for them to exit, and I use something like:

```
process.Start();
int timeout = ... // some normal value in milliseconds

process.WaitForExit(timeout);

try
{
   //ExitCode throws if the process is hanging
   return (CommandErrorCode)process.ExitCode;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
{
   return CommandErrorCode.InternalError;
}
```

where `CommandErrorCode` is something like

```
public enum CommandErrorCode
{
    Success = 0,
    //some other values I know from the processes that are managed
    InternalError = 256 // the ExitCode is a byte, so this out of that range
}
```

Btw, I redirect both standard output and standard error, and use BeginXXXReadLine and the XXXDataReceived handlers, and do not have any issues, but the processes I use are known, well-defined, and well-behaved.

Comment: in the try block above, you mentioned that ExitCode is thrown if process is hanging. Isn't Exit code will be thrown only when process exits and not hangs. Please correct me as i don't know what can happen if process hangs.

Comment: If the process exits normally within the timeout period, `ExitCode` returns a value. If the process hangs, it will not exit at all, and calling `ExitCode` on a running process will result in the throwing of an `InvalidOperationException`. You can also use the `Process.Exited` event and the `Process.Kill` method to manage the process lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet , hope this helps

http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html for cmd.exe help

```
private int CallShell(string exeCommand, string Parameters)
        {
            //http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html
            /*
            This function will actually take the shell string and envoke the appropriate process
             passing it the arguments to do the work
            */

            // Initialize the process and its StartInfo properties.
            System.Diagnostics.Process ProcessEXE = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            logger.DebugFormat("About to Start Process - {0} {1}",exeCommand, Parameters);
            try
            {

                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.FileName = exeCommand;


                // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
                //  false if the process should be created directly from the executable file
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

                //EnableRaisingEvents property indicates whether the component should be notified when the operating system has shut down a process

                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.Arguments = Parameters;

                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                ProcessEXE.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                ProcessEXE.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                ProcessEXE.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived);
                ProcessEXE.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived);

                logger.DebugFormat("Process Started.");
                ProcessEXE.Start();


                // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
                ProcessEXE.BeginErrorReadLine();
                ProcessEXE.BeginOutputReadLine();

                //The WaitForExit overload is used to make the current thread wait until the associated process terminates
                logger.DebugFormat("Process Waiting for exit.");
                ProcessEXE.WaitForExit();

                if (ProcessEXE.ExitCode == 0)
                {
                    logger.Debug(string.Format("Shell Process exited with exit code {0}", ProcessEXE.ExitCode));
                }
                else
                {
                // throw error here if required - check the return error code
                    logger.Warn(string.Format("Shell Process exited with exit code {0}", ProcessEXE.ExitCode));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Method:{0}", ex.TargetSite), ex);
            }

            return ProcessEXE.ExitCode;
        }


void ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
                if (e == null) return;

                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    //No processing
                }
                else
                {
                   // your logic to detect error msg out from output - if at all required
                }

                if (sb.ToString().ToUpper().IndexOf("ERROR") > 0)
                {
                    string smessage = "Error text found in  output.";

                // do your error response action here .

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                logger.ErrorFormat("Error in ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived Message:{0}", exp.Message);
                logger.ErrorFormat("Error in ProcessEXE_OutputDataReceived Data Received:{0}", e.Data);

            // either throw error msg or kill the process 
            }
            finally
            {
                // Not throwing the exception
            }
        }
```